# Python: user definied number format in string

Tags: python, string, format

May be a question that has already been asked:
How can I print an integer in a user definied format.

For example

```
input = 123456
print(".....".format(input))
```

where the output should be:

```
"ab123.45.6"
```

Unfortunately, slicing in string formating is not possible. So something like:

```
"ab{0[:2]}.{0[3:4]}.{0[5]}".format(str(input))
```

would not work.
But is there a better solution than:

```
"ab{0[0]}{0[1]}{0[2]}.{0[3]}{0[4]}.{0[5]}".format(str(input))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the slices `format()` arguments? It looks a bit cleaner.

```
user_input = str(123456)
print("ab{0}.{1}.{2}".format(user_input[:3], user_input[3:5], user_input[5]))
```

Comment: That is in fact a cleaner solution, but still rather clumsy. I would prefer something like "AB####.##" in Excel.